# Angular 2 - How to update a particular value on click

Tags: angular, ionic2

The below code serves as an autocomplete based on Google Places API; once I begin typing some chars on the input fields it starts fetching and showing some places names; what I want to do is that when I click on a `place` that was generated, it replaces the current value of the field I was writing from `knowing that I have 2 input field below` so that I need on `click` that value goes and replace the current value written on a particular field.

```
  <ion-item><ion-input #pickUp (keyup)="updateSearch(pickUp.value)" type="text" placeholder="Pickup"></ion-input></ion-item>
  <ion-item><ion-input #dropOff (keyup)="updateSearch(dropOff.value)" placeholder="Dropoff"></ion-input></ion-item>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" tappable (click)="chooseItem(item)">
       {{ item }}
     </ion-item>
```

I believe that the answer would be implementing `ng-model` but I didn't figure out how to do so in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you insist on using a single list for both inputs, you will have to be able to determine which input you want updated.

This can be achieved by adding a focus (and/or change etc.) event handler on your input elements, and update a flag that keeps the last focused input between those two.

```
<ion-item><ion-input #pickUp (keyup)="updateSearch(pickUp.value)" type="text" placeholder="Pickup" (focus)=setLastFocused("pickup")></ion-input></ion-item>
<ion-item><ion-input #dropOff (keyup)="updateSearch(dropOff.value)" placeholder="Dropoff" (focus)=setLastFocused("dropoff")></ion-input></ion-item>
```

And on your .ts file :

```
private lastFocusedName;

// So now you know which input to update after you "chooseItem(item)"
setLastFocused(inputName){
   lastFocusedName = inputName;
}
```

Now in order to update the values of the input elements you need to get a reference to them using Angular's @ViewChild decorator. More info : 
[Angular.io ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

```
// The ViewChild parameter name must match the template variable name e.g. "#pickup" 

@ViewChild("pickUp") pickUp: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("dropOff") dropOff: ElementRef;

chooseItem(item){
   if(this.lastFocusedName == "pickup"){
      // Update pickup input
      this.pickUp.value = item.value;
   }
   else if(this.lastFocusedName == "dropoff"){
      // Update dropoff input
      this.dropOff.value = item.value;
   }
}
```

Do not forget to import the required modules :

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from "angular2/core";
```